# Stop undefined URL's showing home page

Tags: html

My website stays on the home page if anything is added for example my page seananderson.co.uk
if I type seananderson.co.uk/?page=spam it would display the home page, how should I remove this so that only the page displays on the index.

Comment: What do you want to display instead, a 404 page? Do you have an .htaccess file on your site currently?

Comment: This you cant do it through html alone.

Comment: Yes I do have a .htaccess file, I did play around and couldn't get an error through that.